# EF4 Code only mapping inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef4-code-only

I've got the following model and I want `ShiftRequest` and `MissionRequest` to have a single table in the DB.

```
    public class RequestBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? RequestDate { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }

    }

    public class ShiftRequest : RequestBase
    {
        public virtual Column Column { get; set; }

    }

    public class MissionRequest : RequestBase
    {
        public virtual Mission Mission { get; set; }
    }
```

I've tried to do it in the `override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method but only one `RequestBases` table is created:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ShiftRequest>().MapSingleType().ToTable("dbo.ShiftRequests");
modelBuilder.Entity<MissionRequest>().MapSingleType().ToTable("dbo.MissionRequest");
```

What am I doing wrong?

### EDIT

`Column` and `Mission` are also entities in my model, is that acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the section about TPH in this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/10/12/code-only-further-enhancements.aspx). If Mission and Column are complex types you will also find there how to map them. Generally you have to use MapHiearchy and Case methods instead of MapSingleType.

**Edit:**

Here is the example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;


namespace EFTest
{
    public class RequestBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? RequestedDate { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }

    public class Mission
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<MissionRequest> MissionRequests { get; set; }
    }

    public class Column
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class MissionRequest : RequestBase
    {
        public virtual Mission Mission { get; set; }
    }

    public class ShiftRequest : RequestBase
    {
        public Column Column { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<RequestBase> Requests { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Mission> Missions { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ContainerName = "EFTest";
            modelBuilder.IncludeMetadataInDatabase = false;

            // Example of complex type mapping. First you have to define 
            // complex type. Than you can access type properties in  
            // MapHiearchy.
            var columnType = modelBuilder.ComplexType<Column>();
            columnType.Property(c => c.Name).HasMaxLength(50);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Mission>()
                .Property(m => m.Id)
                .IsIdentity();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Mission>()
                .HasKey(m => m.Id)
                .MapSingleType(m => new { m.Id, m.Name })
                .ToTable("dbo.Missions");

            modelBuilder.Entity<RequestBase>()
                .Property(r => r.Id)
                .IsIdentity();

            // You map multiple entities to single table. You have to  
            // add some discriminator to differ entity type in the table. 
            modelBuilder.Entity<RequestBase>()
                .HasKey(r => r.Id)
                .MapHierarchy()
                .Case<RequestBase>(r => new { r.Id, r.RequestedDate, r.UserId, Discriminator = 0 })
                .Case<MissionRequest>(m => new { MissionId = m.Mission.Id, Discriminator = 1 })
                .Case<ShiftRequest>(s => new { ColumnName = s.Column.Name, Discriminator = 2 })
                .ToTable("dbo.Requests");
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

I updated example. Now Mission is entity instead of complex type.

Comment: do this mean `Mission` and `Column` can't be configured as entities??

Comment: Yes they can. I over looked virtual keyword in your properties and I thought it is inner complex type. But you can define them as navigation properties as well.

Comment: I have midified the example. Now Mission is an entity. You can use same approach for Column.

Comment: Do you use column in multiple inherited entities?